# Annotation Browser view Problem in UIMA RUTA

Tags: uima, ruta

I'm running same set of script and input in older version of uima ruta 2.8.1 in that Annotation Browser view is opening fine. But while using UIMA RUTA version 3.1.0(same script and input also same) but here Annotation Browser view is not opening error as shown as below screenshot.[image: Annotation Browser view]

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to provide more memory for your Eclipse, i.e. increase the maximum Java Heap size. This can be done with e.g. -Xmx5000m in your eclipse.ini.

There are several blog post and stackoverflow questions with detailed howtos.